# List<List<String>> mapped to List<String>

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mapstruct

I'm learning how to use Mapstruct in a Spring Boot and Kotlin project.

I've got a generated DTO (ThessaurusDTO) that has a List and I need this mapped into a List on my model (Vocab).

It makes sense that MapStruct can't map this automatically, but I know for a fact that the first list will always be size = 1. I have no control on the API the DTO model belongs to. 
I found on the [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods) that I can create define a default method implementation within the interface, which would loosely translate to a normal function in Kotlin

My mapper interface:

```
@Mapper
interface VocabMapper {

    @Mappings(
            // ...
    )
    fun thessaurusToVocab(thessaurusDTO: ThessaurusDTO): Vocab

    fun metaSyns(nestedList: List<List<String>>): List<String> 
             = nestedList.flatten()
}
```

When I try to do a build I get the following error:

```
VocabMapper.java:16: error: Can't map collection element "java.util.List<java.lang.String>" to "java.lang.String ". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.String map(java.util.List<java.lang.String> value)".
```

It looks like mapStruct is still trying to automatically do the mapping while ignoring my custom implementation. Am I missing something trivial here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found on the documentation that I can create define a default method implementation within the interface, which would loosely translate to a normal function in Kotlin
>
> From my understand of what I found online, Kotlin does not properly translate an interface function into a default method in Java, but actually generates a class that implements the interface.

If that's the problem, you can annotate `metaSyns` with [`@JvmDefault`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-default/):

> > Specifies that a JVM default method should be generated for non-abstract Kotlin interface member.
> >
> > Usages of this annotation require an explicit compilation argument to be specified: either `-Xjvm-default=enable` or `-Xjvm-default=compatibility`.

See the link for the difference, but you probably need `-Xjvm-default=enable`.

Comment: This is the correct approach. Just FYI in case something still doesn't work correctly have a look at [KT-25960](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25960) there is a bug in the Kotlin annotation processing, such that it does not expose everything to the annotation processor

Answer (score 0):

I've seen to have fixed this by relying on an abstract based implementation, instead of using an interface.
From my understand of what I found online, Kotlin does not properly translate an interface function into a default method in Java, but actually generates a class that implements the interface.

https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1577